# Cross-browser CSS issue when changing font-weight

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a weird problem going on in my project. I have a navigation menu where, when you *hover* it will change the *font-weight* from 400 to 900. It works just fine in Apple based products. However, when I try it on windows, by hovering over the links they get messed up, the Font Awesome icon goes over the font for some reason... Can anyone make any sense of this?

Before Hover

[image]

After Hover

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @thesecretmaster i figured out what it was, it was a padding that comes with bootstrap...

Comment: That you should write up an answer. What if someone else comes and finds this question? Don't you want to share the answer with them?

Comment: This question needs to be closed since it "works as expected".

Answer (score 0):

It was the default bootstrap padding that was to blame for the problem